In PyTorch, when the nn.linear operation(fp32) only increases the shape size, the result that certain parts are not the same. (SNR is not infinity)
test = nn.Linear(1440, 1440, bias=False)
hidden1 = torch.randn(400, 1440, dtype=torch.float32)
hidden2 = hidden1[:100, :]
output1 = test(hidden1)
output2 = test(hidden2)

If I test it as above,
shouldn't the output1 and output2[:100,:] parts be exactly the same?
There are slightly different parts, do you know why?
It should be the same as simple matmul calculation, but it is different.

What do you mean by "slightly different parts"? output1.shape should be Size([100, 1440]) and output2.shape should be Size([400, 1440]). The actual values in output1 and output2[:100] should be different because hidden1 and hidden2[:100] are different.

I think the results of the two operations should be the same at the beginning, but they are a little different. (SNR is not infinity)
Shouldn't hidden1 and hidden2[:100] be the same?

You seem to be confused about what torch.randn does.  hidden1 and hidden2[:100] are almost certainly not equal since they are filled with different random samples.

Ah, sorry, I wrote down the wrong question.
I updated the question.
This is the case when linear for the same value.
